# c struct and function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I am trying to create some c modules that has functions to internal functions without using c++, that I can then update and add features to while keeping things relatively clean and modular coding wise.

Let's say for example I have a simple math module that i'd like to continue to add functions to.

math.h

```
struct math;
struct ops;

struct math
{
    int id;
    struct ops* m_ops;
};

struct ops
{
    int (* add)(int* a, int* b);
    int (* sub)(int* a, int* b);    
};
```

with this setup if I continue to add functions to the struct ops; this will keep the size of my original math struct the same and can also maintain binary compatibility and things like that. I don't plan on having multiple implementation of these functions.

so with this simple setup, how can I init these functions? Currently I am doing something like this which seems a bit tedious, is there a nicer way to get it done. Maybe a language like c++ hides all this but I am looking for best practices without using c++ as I would like to know what's really going on.

```
int add(int *a, int*b)
{
    return ((*a) + (*b));
}

int sub(int *a, int*b)
{
    return ((*a) - (*b));
}
```

main.c

```
    struct test* t_test = (struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    math->id = 3;
    math->m_ops = (struct m_ops*)malloc(sizeof(struct m_ops));
    math->m_ops->add = &add;
    math->m_ops->sub = &sub;

    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    printf("adding: %d\n",math->m_ops->add(&a, &b));
```

would the malloc of both structs be put in some init function in math.h or something like that? I am not sure, I've been looking for examples of code that does this but either I don't know where to look because I just can't find any.

Comment: Why are you using function pointers in `struct`s when the functions don't even take either `struct` as argument?

Comment: This is unanswerable until you explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: @this I wan to create a module that I can include into a larger project. This class math.h will have helper functions that I can add to as time goes on and the need arises for more functionality from the math library.

Comment: IMO, there's no point mallocing the m_ops struct unless you're doing some super fancy stuff like creating C functions at runtime. Put that in static memory.

Comment: if you use malloc, you also must use free.

Answer (score 3):

You're not *really* trying to make a class, but a module. Your `id` isn't actually in use anywhere.  This sort of thing is done from time to time in C, but it's not a very common pattern.  It also inhibits a lot of possible optimizations but here it is:

```
static int add_impl(int *a, int *b) {
    return *a + *b;
}

static int sub_impl(int *a, int *b) {
    return *a + *b;
}

static struct {
    int (*add)(int*, int*); // pointer to the add function
    int (*sub)(int*, int*);
} math_ops = {
    add_impl, // .add = add_impl
    sub_impl
};
```

and then called with

```
int x = 2;
int y = 1;
math_ops.add(&x, &y);
```

---

If you want to expose the minimum amount in a header (**recommended**), you can separate it as follows:

mymath.h

```
struct math_ops_tag {
    int (*add)(int*, int*);
    int (*sub)(int*, int*);
};

extern struct math_ops_tag math_ops;
```

mymath.c

```
#include "mymath.h"

static int add_impl(int *a, int *b) {
    return *a + *b;
}

static int sub_impl(int *a, int *b) {
    return *a + *b;
}

struct math_ops_tag math_ops = {
    add_impl,
    sub_impl
};
```

If you can use C99 then I'd recommend instead defining `math_ops` as

```
struct math_ops_tag math_ops = {
    .add = add_impl,
    .sub = sub_impl
};
```

to avoid mispositioning anything

Comment: thanks for this, one of the main reason for trying to do put the functions in a struct is also to maintain binary compatibility so that future updates don't break past code, etc.

Comment: @mroh Can you explain how binary compatibility of having a `struct` with constant pointers to functions is better than exposing those functions directly? If you change the target of the pointers the users of your module still need the updated binary which to set the new targets in the `struct`.

Comment: @mroh this doesn't address that problem

Comment: @mroh An opaque pointer can be used to hide the format of a `struct` from its user (i.e., they could call `function(structptr)` but they would not know what fields the `struct` has. However, if they are calling `structptr->function`, then `structptr` cannot be opaque. For a single compilation unit (~source file) you can just use `static` functions. For sharing `static` functions _across your own code_ you could indeed use a `struct` with function pointers, but that `struct` does not need to be shared with the module's user (or it defeats the purpose). None of this helps “binary compatibility”.

Comment: @Arkku thanks for helping me clear this up. I came from a C++ object oriented field but I would like to move towards C99 standard because I really don't need many of the features offered by C++ and I spend a lot of time writing code that does nothing. It's not a bash against C++ it's just my experience. I would like to use C and get the C++ cruft out of my head.

Comment: @mroh then just use functions.  In C++ the closest thing to this would be a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your literal question is: provide a “constructor” function to initialize the `struct`(s), i.e., instead of allocating `struct math` themselves, the user of your module would do something like:

```
 struct math *math = newMath();
```

The function would do the necessary setup before returning the allocated `struct` to the user.

However, I don't think your approach makes any sense. Your functions do not take either the containing `struct math` or `struct ops` as argument, so they should be just regular functions (i.e., just put `int sub(int *a, int*b);` in the header directly and the user of your module can call `sub(&i, &j)`). And if you wish to make “private” functions, make them `static` and do not introduce them in the header.

Or if you wish to simulate a C++-style class with `struct`s, make the first argument of each function a pointer to the related `struct math` (of course the function should then make use of the state of the `struct` for this to make sense). You still don't need function pointers for this, though.

Having function pointers in the `struct` would only be useful different `struct math` instances in the same program need to have a different implementation for, say, `sub`, *and* those instances would need to be interchangeable. That is, if `math1->ops->sub` and `math2->ops->sub` would point to a different function, and somewhere in the code you would need to call an unknown `someMath->ops->sub` without knowing which type it is, then it might be justified to have the pointers. In all other scenarios you should ditch `struct ops`.

Comment: As an additional observation, `math.h` is a standard library header name, so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Yes, to clarify: I meant that the OP shouldn't use the file name `math.h` for their own header (which is shown in the question, not referenced in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `struct`s for grouping functions to make things modular.
Use symbol prefixes (C's poor man's namespaces) to group functions.

(Unless your goal is runtime polymorphism like `C++`s virtual methods. Then your on the right track--`m_ops` is your `vtable`, and like `C++`'s `vtables`, you should initialize it statically, i.e.: without `malloc`)

It seems like you're sort of trying to emulate C++ while "knowing what's really going on"..

What's really going on in C++'s classes is that although C++ speaks of "member" functions, there's no functions pointers and function tables involved at all, unless your class has virtual functions.

At the object file level C++ methods are just free-standing functions made out of methods by adding an implicit instance pointer argument, 
prefixing the method name with the class's name and mangling the result.

---

Also, don't pass ints by pointers. Pass them by values. `int`s tend to take less or as much space as pointers. Passing ints by pointers makes things less efficient because you pass more data and have worse (or no) locality.

Comment: it's okay to use structs for ops and function pointers to group things together especially if there are many different drivers for the operations.

Comment: "especially if there are many different drivers for the operations" --> then it's  the virtual-function-like runtime polymorphism. I don't think it's a good practice in any other case. It adds unecessary runtime overheads as opposed to grouping things together by a common prefix.

Comment: bah :) if runtime overhead is an issue there are numerous ways to optimize a couple of memory lookups out. the advantages of code cleanliness and modularity (that the OP wants) far outweigh a few memory lookups; heck one can use a double pointer and bind the op directly to the target object and you're golden.  and it's super clean and you can inject code at runtime.